# Even after adding key prop console returns list should have unique key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of object. I'm fetching data from that array. I tried key prop on both first and second `div`. But console still returning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

```js
const data = [
  {
    itemNo: 1,
    itemImage: [
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-alien"
        width="44"
        height="44"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke-width="1.5"
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
      >
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
        <path d="M11 17a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2 0" />
        <path d="M12 3c-4.664 0 -7.396 2.331 -7.862 5.595a11.816 11.816 0 0 0 2 8.592a10.777 10.777 0 0 0 3.199 3.064c1.666 1 3.664 1 5.33 0a10.777 10.777 0 0 0 3.199 -3.064a11.89 11.89 0 0 0 2 -8.592c-.466 -3.265 -3.198 -5.595 -7.862 -5.595z" />
        <line x1="8" y1="11" x2="10" y2="13" />
        <line x1="16" y1="11" x2="14" y2="13" />
      </svg>
    ],
    name: "John Doe",
    address: "New York"
  }
]

const Names = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      {data.map(({ itemNo, itemImage, name, address }) => (
        <div key={itemNo}>
          <div>
            <div>{itemImage}</div>
            <div>
              <div>{name}</div>
              <div>{address}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Key should be on the outermost mapped element, check, but they also need to be unique among siblings. Can you share the real data being mapped? Or is that really it, the single element?

Comment: I am using svg in that array.

Comment: I see, then I believe you need to map the `itemImage` array. Providing a react key of course.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `itemImage` is an array it also needs to be mapped. Using a react `Fragment` would be the easiest way to enclose the svg element in a tag and provide a key.

```
const Names = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      {data.map(({ itemNo, itemImage, name, address }) => (
        <div key={itemNo}>
          <div>
            <div>
              {itemImage.map((el, i) => <Fragment key={i}>{el}</Fragment>)}
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>{name}</div>
              <div>{address}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}
```